# RESTful URI to select "My" items

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to expose my `Item` resource in these ways:

```
GET /Item (to show all Items)
GET /Item/401 (to show only the Item with key value 401)
```

So far so good. Now to request *only the Items that belong to Me,* I can think of these possible URIs constructions:

```
GET /Item/Mine
GET /MyItem
GET /Item/owner=42 (where my ID is 42)
```

I don't like the last one because it simplifies my client programming to rely on existing authentication to figure out "My" ID. I happen to be coding on ASP.NET WebAPI, but I'm really asking about the principle and design, not the implementation.

My question: Which of the three ways to represent "My" Items is most consistent with the RESTful design concept? Is it even legitimate to ask for "My" Items as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users should not be able to see items that aren't "theirs", then this is an authorization issue. Just use GET /Item, and have your authorization module strip out the items that aren't theirs.

If users can see all items, and you just want to grab the items that belong to a particular user, then you should be parameterizing the call to GET /Item. Something like GET /Item/?owner=42. In this case, the user isn't limited to asking for their items .. they can ask for the items of any owner. That buys them flexibility without costing you anything.

If you have a /User resource, you could also add an endpoint /User/{id}/Item, which
returns the same collection as /Item/?owner=

And this isn't germane, but I find that plural collections (/Items, /Users) read a lot better than singulars. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `GET /Items` to get all itmes.

And `GET /Items?owner=42`.

`GET /Item/Mine` is not consistent since it contradicts your way of identifying the resource ie, 
 `GET /Item/401`.

`GET /MyItem` seems seems unnecessary since the resources you are looking for can be retrieved using the other REST url paths.